# Rotation UIImageView around An anchorPoint

Tags: ios

i want to rotate multiple UIImageView around anchor point and give them a little rotation so that could be something like this

[https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=cards.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=zzkjUoXFL5GWswbrrIGgBw&biw=1024&bih=615&sei=0TkjUu2wHcmntAbC54Bo#facrc=*&imgdii=*&imgrc=BdArJtkexKgyQM%3A%3BnKsOa4ZSkOOFcM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fdailywicca.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F10%252Fplaying-cards1.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fdailywicca.com%252F2011%252F10%252F08%252Freading-with-a-plain-deck-of-cards%252F%3B1920%3B1200](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=cards.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=zzkjUoXFL5GWswbrrIGgBw&biw=1024&bih=615&sei=0TkjUu2wHcmntAbC54Bo#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=BdArJtkexKgyQM:;nKsOa4ZSkOOFcM;http%253A%252F%252Fdailywicca.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F10%252Fplaying-cards1.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fdailywicca.com%252F2011%252F10%252F08%252Freading-with-a-plain-deck-of-cards%252F;1920;1200)

this is my code i think it should work but wear thing happened

```
int angel=0;

for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150)];
    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angel);

    angel+=3;
}
```

[image]

i think they all should be in the same side as iam increasing angle with 3 , how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` takes radians as input, not degrees. Now, you could easily convert from degrees to radians using a macro like this:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

Or you could just use smaller input values. In radians, 360 degrees is equal to 2 * π ~ 6.28, so instead of ranging your values assuming 0-360, you should assume 0-2π. When you increase the value by 3, you're effectively increasing it by just under 180 degrees, which is why you're seeing what you are.

Overall, try using `angel += 0.052539;`. You'll need to change `angel` from an int to a float as @Kyle W. pointed out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question, but try this:

Change the angle from an `int` to a `float`.

```
float angel = 0;
```

Change the increment for each iteration of the loop.

```
angel += 0.3;
```

Also, I think you mean "angle" not "angel" ;)